# AngularJS: newline characters to paragraph elements

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Within Angular, I need to  generate a series of paragraph elements from a block of text containing newline characters?

I can think of a couple of ways to do this. However I am wondering whether there is an "official" Angular way or just what the most elegant approach would be within the AngularJS context.

### An Example

From:

> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. \n
>   Sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore. \n
>   Magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam.

to:

```
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.</p>
<p>Sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore.</p>
<p>Magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam.</p>
```

I can think of a number of ways to do this:

1. Modify the text in the controller (though I prefer to avoid modifying my models)
2. Using a directive, and generating paragraphs in a link function (seems overly cumbersome).
3. Using a filter (my current favourite) to create an array to pipe into ng-repeat

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The best solution I could think of was to create a filter:

```
angular.module('myApp').
filter('nlToArray', function() {
  return function(text) {
      return text.split('\n');
  };
});
```

This takes a block of text and creates a new array element for each paragraph.

This array can then be plugged into an ng-repeat directive:

```
<p ng-repeat="paragraph in textBlock|nlToArray track by $index">{{paragraph}}</p>
```

Comment: seems like a bit of extra overhead and unsafe.

Answer (score 5):

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['ngSanitize']);
myApp.controller('myCtrl', function($scope){
    $scope.myText = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.\nSed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore.\nMagna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam."
});
myApp.filter('nl2p', function () {
    return function(text){
        text = String(text).trim();
        return (text.length > 0 ? '<p>' + text.replace(/[\r\n]+/g, '</p><p>') + '</p>' : null);
    }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/moderndegree/934aZ/

Comment: This approach will trim the string and then place the HTML into the DOM using Angular's ngSanitize. This should make it a little harder for someone to try to insert malicious markup.

Comment: The only downside to this approach is that it nests the resulting paragraph elements within another DOM element. In your example a <span>. But, that is a pretty minor downside.

Comment: don't forget to include the ngSanitize module and JS file

Comment: Fantastic, BUT the regex needs to end with g to make the replacement more than once (e.g. `/[\r\n]+/g`). Linky: http://jsfiddle.net/934aZ/47/

Answer (score 2):

You might solve this with **css** property and use  {{text}} into **p** html element

```
 white-space: pre-line;
```

Comment: This is really a very good alternative approach. It does not add multiple paragraphs like requested, but in most cases the visual result is the same.

Answer (score 0):

This is a silly hack, but it works around paragraphs being enclosed around other tags, such as `<p><h3>`:

```
text = '<p>' + text.replace(/[\r\n]+/g, '</p><p>') + '</p>';
// delete blank lines
text = text.replace(/<p>\s*?<\p>/g, '');
// delete erroneous paragraph enclosed tags
text = text.replace(/<p>\s*?(<.+?>)\s*?(.+?)\s*?(<\/.+?>)\s*?<\/p>/g, '$1$2$3');
```